# Degree of a subvariety of the Grassmannian

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, intersection-theory, grassmannian, schubert-calculus

This might be a stupid question due to my lack of knowledge in algebraic geometry.
So I have a subvariety $V\subset G_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$ of codimension $k$. The only thing I know about $V$ is its cohomology class Poincare - dual to its fundamental class $[V] \in H_*(G_k(\mathbb{C}^n))$ and its codimension. That is, I have $$[V]^* := PD^{-1}([V]) \in H^{2r}(G_k(\mathbb{C}^n)),$$
where $r =\text{codim}(V)$.

If $V$ was a subvariety of the projective space $\mathbb{P}^N$, I would take the cup - product of $[V]^*$ with the (Schubert - ) class $c_1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^N}(1))^{N-r} = \sigma_1^{N-r}$ of a generic $r$ - plane in $\mathbb{P}^N$ to get its degree (right?).

But since the Grassmannian $G_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$ is only embedded into some $\mathbb{P}^N$ via Plücker - embedding, I don't know what the "class of a generic $r$ - plane" in the Grassmannian looks like.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The degree of a variety is defined with respect to its embedding into a projective space (or, more generally, with respect to an ample divisor class), so in your case the degree is the cup-product with $c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))^{M-r}$, where $M = \binom{n}{k}$ is the dimension of the Grassmannian.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. One question: $c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))$ does not even lie in the same cohomology ring as $[V]^*$, does it? Or do you consider the Grassmannian and $V$ as subvarieties of $\mathbb{P}^M$ (via Plücker embedding)?

Comment: By $\mathcal{O}(1)$ I mean the Plucker line bundle on the Grassmannian, that is the restriction of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ via the Plucker embedding.

Comment: I see, I get the idea. I have read in Eisenbud&Harris "3264 and all that", that "..the hyperplane class on $\mathbb{P}(\wedge^2\mathbb{k}^{n+1})$ pulls back to the class $\sigma_1\in A^1(G(2,n+1))$" under the Plücker embedding. But they don't explain things further (maybe it's supposed to be obvious). Is this for any Grassmannian? Or differently: How can $c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))$ be expressed via Schubert classes? I struggle to find references...

Comment: @Teddyboer If I don't have things backwards, $c_1(\mathcal O(1))$ is $\sigma_1$ in any Grassmannian.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. I found some notes called "subvarieties of Grassmannians" by E.Arrondo. The things I was looking for were partly answered on page 15 - 16. The comments helped a lot, since they pointed me into the right direction